# How to get JDL or JH file from the existing jhipster project

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

Is there a way to get JH file that i used to import into my JHipster project.  I am able to see list of json files inside .jhipster folder.  But where i can find jh file and how to get that back.  So that i can do modifications and import it again.  For example how can i get the jh file for this below sample jhipster project.

Import command

```
yo jhipster:import-jdl ~/Downloads/example.jh
```

https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the same, instead of import, it's export. 
Here all possible commands:

`yo jhipster:export-jdl`

`yo jhipster:export-jdl jhipster.jh`

`jhipster export-jdl`

`jhipster export-jdl jhipster.jh`

Comment: The prefered way now is 'jhipster export-jdl ouput.jh'